# TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable (nested functions)

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, int, typeerror

So, whenever I call a function that calls another function I get this TypeError and I don't know why because it doesn't happen when I call first function. Here's the code:

```
def codeChar(c,key):
    k = ord(c) + key
    if key > 26:
        key = key % 26
    if 91 <= k <= 96:
        k = k - 26
    elif 123 <= k:
        k = k - 26
    c = chr(k)
    return c

def codeBlock(word,key):
    i = 0
    result = ""
    while i < len(word):
        k = int(key[i])
        result = result + codeChar(word[i],k)
        i = i + 1
    return result

def isletter(h):
    i = ord(h)
    if 65 <= i <= 90:
        return True
    elif 97 <= i <= 122:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def codeString(string,key):
    i = 0
    result = ""
    while i < len(string):
        k = int(key[i])
        if isletter(string[i]) == True:
            result = result + codeBlock(string[i],k)
            i = i + 1
        else:
            i = i + 1
    return result

print(codeString(input("Enter a sentence to be coded: "),input("Enter an 8 digit key: ")))
```

The error code received when I run it is this:

```
Enter a sentence to be coded: Hello world
Enter your student number: 16061226
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\cw.1\cw.1.py", line 89, in <module>
    print(codeString(input("Enter a sentence to be coded: "),input("Enter your student number: ")))
  File "E:\cw.1\cw.1.py", line 82, in codeString
    result = result + codeBlock(string[i],k)
  File "E:\cw.1\cw.1.py", line 39, in codeBlock
    k = key[i]
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where does the error occur?  What was the entire error message?

Comment: Just added that, realised I had forgotten to mention it

Answer (score 0):

When you pass `k` to `codeBlock` on line 36, it's an integer, rather than the string that your function is expecting. Perhaps you intended to use `key` here instead?

Comment: When I use key I receive IndexError: string index is out of range for the `result = result + codeBlock(string[i],key[i])` line

Comment: This is due to your assumption that the string is shorter than the key. If the string is longer than the key, then you'll get the error you described.

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with calling a function from another function. When you call `codeBlock` from within `codeString`, you pass it a parameter k, which is an integer. On the other side, with `key` in the `codeBlock` function, you try to index into that integer by doing `int(key[i])`, hence the typeError.